# ¿Cuál es el error con el .FORMAT(VA1,VA2,VA3,VA4) ?, no me imprime simétrico

Tags: python, consola, formato, print

Muy buenas noches. Mi problema es el siguiente: El problema es que intento que me muestre por consola de tal manera que los quiero de la forma siguiente:

```
nombre   horaEntrada   HoraSalida    DuracionLugar
Johan       09:10         03:40          06:30
```

Por desgracia. me muestra como esta en la siguiente imagen. No lo logro que el formato me de de tal forma que no me de ese salto de linea.

ojala me puedan ayudar, ya que es un proyecto que quiero desarrollar como practica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def main():

    vector = []
    
    archivo = open("horaMin.txt")
    desarrollo(archivo, vector)
    input("- Pulse enter para salir del programa....")
    archivo.close()
    

def desarrollo(archivo, vector):
    

    for i in archivo:

        vector = i.split(",")
        nom = vector[0]
        entrada = vector[1]
        salida = vector[2]

        #hora de entrada
        horaE = vector[1]
        horaE = int(horaE[:-3])
        minE = vector[1]
        minE = int(minE[3:])

        #hora de salida
        horaS = vector[2]
        horaS = int(horaS[:2])
        minS = vector[2]
        minS = int(minS[3:])

        #funcion para condicionales de Duracion
        tardoM, tardoH = duracion(horaE, minE, horaS, minS) 

        result = organizoDuracion(tardoM, tardoH)

        print(" {0:10} {1:8} {2:8} {3:2}".format(nom,entrada,salida,result))

def organizoDuracion(tardoM, tardoH):

    if tardoM < 10:#condicional, de si, cuando se menor a 10 el min, le agrege un cero: ejemplo en vez de 9, 09 min

        tardoM = "0"+str(tardoM)#Agregamos el Cero

    if tardoH < 10:# lo mismo, en vez que aparezca 5 horas, aparezca 05 horas
        
        tardoH = "0"+str(tardoH)#Agregamos el Cero

    else:

        tardoH = str(tardoH)

    result = str(tardoH) +":"+str(tardoM)

    return result
    

def duracion(horaE, minE, horaS, minS):

    if horaS == 12:

        duracion = ((horaS*60) + minS ) - ((horaE*60) + minE)
        duraM = duracion % 60
        duraH = (duracion - duraM)/60

        return duraM, int(duraH)

    elif horaS < 12:

        horaS = horaS + 12

        if horaE >= 7 and horaE <= 12:

            duracion = ((horaS*60) + minS ) - ((horaE*60) + minE)
            duraM = duracion % 60
            duraH = (duracion - duraM)/60

            return duraM, int(duraH)
            
        elif horaE >= 0 and horaE < 7:

            horaE = horaE + 12
            duracion = ((horaS*60) + minS ) - ((horaE*60) + minE)
            duraM = duracion % 60
            duraH = (duracion - duraM)/60

            return duraM, int(duraH)
        
    

main()
```

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que el retorno de carro forme ya parte de la cadena que has leido del archivo. Puedes eliminar los retornos de carro que haya en el archivo al momento de leerlos, como parte del bucle  `for i in archivo:`  usando `strip()`. Por ejemplo en la primera línea de ese bucle en que asignas `vector` puedes cambiarlo a `vector = i.strip().split(",")` Eso eliminará el retorno de carro que haya al final de la línea, antes de aplicarle el split. Sin eso, el retorno de carro estaría aún ahí e iriía a parar al último elemento de `vector`.

Comment: muchas gracias. me ha ayudado muchisimo.